# Why cache memory is filling too fast on my mobile device. Is there any code to solve this issue?

Tags: android, caching

When I install app on my mobile, cache memory is filling very fast to approximately 50 mb. I think it may spoil the device what might be the reason and how to fix it

Thanks inAdvance

Answer (score 1):

Amount of accumulated cache data entirely depends on the app. Some apps need to cache a lot of data, pictures and even videos (i.e. Facebook, Instagram, WhatsApp), also there are apps that do not have good memory management, they rarely (if at all) clear they caches - this can result in significant memory consumption.

In any case, however, your Android OS manages the memory on your device, and in most cases, you don't have to worry about it. It definitely won't "spoil the device".

If you are really annoyed by the amount of cache stored by any particular app, you can simply clear it from Application in 3 simple steps:

> 1) Go to the Settings menu. This can be done by tapping the cog
>   icon in your notification shade.
>
> 2) Find App (or Applications, depending on your device) in the
>   menu, then locate the app that you want to clear the cache or data
>   for.
>
> 3) Tap on Storage and the buttons for clearing the cache and app
>   data will become available (pictured above).